# Git rebase -i HEAD~n not working

Tags: git, rebase

I'm trying to edit a commit message that has already been pushed.
I'm following [these](https://superuser.com/questions/751699/is-there-a-way-to-edit-a-commit-message-in-github/751909) steps which are basically Rebase → Reword → Push.

The problem is that `git rebase -i HEAD~3` doesn't show only the last 3 commits but the last 20! Even if I do `git rebase -i <commit_hash>` I have 20 commits shown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did any of last 3 commits are merge commit?

Comment: @PetSerAl yes, the last commit is a merge commit.

Comment: Likely you have to remake the merge with the new base. Reset your head one step back, do the rebase, repeat the merge with the new head

Comment: same issue here but I don't have any merge commit in my last `n` commits

Answer (score 1):

Before getting into an answer, I should preface this with a warning: Regardless of how you do it, editing a commit message involves [rewriting history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) in git. **This is not something you should do for commits you have pushed to branches other people might checkout or work on top of (e.g. `master`).** Once you have pushed commits to a branch like master, you should consider those commits to be permanent/set in stone. Unless you have a VERY good reason (e.g. you pushed a commit that included something security sensitive like your private ssh key), you shouldn't be re-writing that history.

Second, this won't fix your problem, but, assuming `<commit_hash>` is referring to the hash of the commit you want to edit, `git rebase -i <commit_hash>` is incorrect. The correct version, which is given in the instructions you linked, is actually `git rebase -i <commit_hash>^` (Note the `^` at the end). Rebase doesn't include the argument you passed, so if you want to edit `<commit_hash>`, the commit you have to pass to rebase is the one before that (i.e. `<commit_hash>^`).

---

As @Sergio mentioned, the cause of this is probably a merge commit among the last 3 commits. Rebase doesn't play very nicely with merge commits for a variety of reasons.

While it's not impossible to rebase a merge commit, there isn't a single clear, sensible way of doing that, and so there are a couple different options for telling git how to do that. In addition, there are also lots of subtle intricacies to the process of rebasing a merge commit that might be a little hard to explain if you're not familiar with git.

If you don't have enough knowledge to figure out how to do it from the git docs, what I would recommend doing instead is a more manual equivalent:

1. Tag your current commit in case you make a mistake and need to revert or start over: `git tag temp`. Also, while you're at it, check that you don't have any unstaged or uncommitted changes using `git status`
2. Reset to the commit you want to edit the message for: `git reset --hard HEAD~3`
3. Edit the commit message with `git commit --amend`
4. Re-create the other changes on top of your new, modified commit with the updated commit message. For the non-merge commits, you can use cherry-pick to copy them over. For the merge commit(s) you'll have to re-do it using `git merge` just like when you created them the first time around. If there are conflicts, re-resolve them. If the merge included some manual amendments, you'll need to re-do those as well.
5. Double check the result using `git diff temp` and `git range-diff HEAD...temp`. If it's not right, or at any point in the process you realize you made a mistake, you can start over with `git reset --hard temp`.
6. Push your changes: `git push --force-with-lease` (`--force-with-lease` is safer alternative to `--force`)
7. If everything worked, you can now delete the tag: `git tag -d temp`.

This is pretty much the same thing as what `git rebase -i --rebase-merges=no-rebase-cousins` would do, but with a much lower potential for confusion or mistakes if you're new to git.

One final note: If the commit you want to edit is the merge commit, and there are not other merge commits after that, you have another option that lets you get around the issue of rebasing a merge commit. Instead of rebasing the commit you want to edit, only rebase the commits after it, but insert a break at the very start of the to-do list (before the `pick <hash> message` lines).  That way, you can edit the merge commit using `git commit --amend` before rebase starts re-applying the commits. Then, when it does re-applying the commits, it will do so on top of your newly modified merge.